# How to check 2 Textboxes for data in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net

First, I want to Check the Textbox1 for some data and if it is empty, then do not display anything at all. But if there's some data in Textbox1, i now want to check Textbox 2 whether it is empty or not... If the textbox2 is empty then display only the text in the textbox1 but if the textbox2 has some data in it, then display "Textbox1 + Textbox2" data.

Here's some code i've written, but i'm not successful to get the desired output.

```
Dim CheckText As String
    If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox1.Text)) Then
    ElseIf (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox2.Text)) Then
        CheckText = String.Format("<a href={0}{1}{0}>{2} by {3}</a>{4}{4}</div>", qmQuotes, Link1.Text, Textbox.Text, xyz.Text, Environment.NewLine)
    Else
        CheckText = String.Format("<a href={0}{1}{0}>{2}: {4} by {3}</a>{5}{5}</div>", qmQuotes, Link1.Text, Textbox.Text, xyz.Text, abc.Text, Environment.NewLine)
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you used `ElseIf` instead of a second nested `If`.

So if `Textbox1.Text` was not empty, the runtime never reaches any CheckText part.
If it was empty and `Textbox2.Text` was not , the `ElseIf` part was executed.
If both were empty the `Else` part had been executed.
Here is the corrected code:

```
Dim CheckText As String
If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox1.Text)) Then
    If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox2.Text)) Then
       CheckText = String.Format("{0}...", Textbox1.Text)
    Else
       CheckText = String.Format("{0}{1}...", Textbox1.Text, Textbox2.Text)
    End If
End If
```

I shortened the `String.Format` part since it was not obvious to me which exact text you want to display.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brother... worked like a charm and a great explanation too